# What will be the most useful quantum algorithms in the fault-tolerant quantum computers era?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm, fault-tolerance

When we'll have fault tolerant quantum computers with a lot of qubits, what will be the most useful algorithms (studied so far)? I know about Shor, Grover and quantum phase estimation but I'm pretty sure there is a lot more (even applications of the algorithms cited above).

I'm interested also in applications in all fields (Machine learning, finance, Physics, etc.).

I know that is a really generic question, but any algorithm that I don't know about can be useful to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you look at https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/? If not, take a look. I think it will worth your time.

Comment: the standard reference here is https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00862